# Collective Hamiltonian of a crystal from Fourier transform

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, fourier-transform, crystals

I am reading some notes from my professor and I couldn't follow this argument. We are considering the Hamiltonian for a very general quantum crystal:
$$
\hat{H}=\sum_{\vec{x}, \vec{\delta}} \frac{\hat{P}^{2}(\vec{x})}{2 m}+\frac{1}{2} m \omega_{0}^{2}(\hat{X}(\vec{x})-\hat{X}(\vec{x}+\vec{\delta}))^{2}
$$

where $\vec{x}$ labels the lattice site and $\vec{\delta}$ is the spacing between sites. My professor says that we can write the hamiltonian in reciprocal space and split it into a collective and an internal part:
$$
\hat{H}=\hat{H}_{\mathrm{coll}}+\sum_{\vec{k} \neq 0} \hat{H}_{\mathrm{int}}(\vec{k}).
$$

He further states that the collective part (which I am interpreting as meaning "the part the considers the crystal as moving as a whole and not the internal vibrations") will correspond to the $\vec{k} = 0$ mode in the expansion. I don't understand why the latter is the case. Why is it that when we take the fourier transform of the crystal's hamiltonian the zero mode will correspond the the part of the hamiltonian that only considers the motions of the crystal (as opposed to internal vibrations)?

Comment: For your Hamiltonina to make sense,  $\vec \delta$ should be index for the nearest neighbor sites. And the $\hat X(\vec x)$ means the displacement (away  from the position $\vec x$) of the lattice point at site $\vec x$?

Comment: @ytlu Yes, that is the case.